# requiredFieldError doesnt work

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flex4

It seems like a code written right but I don't get an error message when I try to skip first name field. Instead I see a little yellow triangle with an exclamation mark in it, that appears next to the first name field. What can be a reason for this? Thanks.

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:RadioButtonGroup id="phoneRadioButtonGroup"/>
    <mx:StringValidator id="firstNameValidator" source="{firstNameTextInput}"
    property="text" requiredFieldError="This field is required" required="true"/>
    <mx:StringValidator id="lastNameValidator" source="{lastNameTextInput}" 
    property="text" required="false" tooShortError="Please enter at least four characters" minLength="4"/>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Form width="380" height="615" backgroundColor="#56A1B9">
    <s:FormHeading label="Contact Editor"/>

    <s:FormItem width="252" height="36" label="First Name" required="true">
    <s:TextInput id="firstNameTextInput"/>
    </s:FormItem>

    <s:FormItem width="251" height="36" label="Last Name" required="false"> 
    <s:TextInput id="lastNameTextInput"/>
    </s:FormItem>

    <mx:HRule width="100%" height="15"/>

    <s:FormItem width="252" height="37" label="Email" required="true">
    <s:TextInput id="emailTextInput"/>
    </s:FormItem>
```

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, in this framework, that little exclamation mark in the triangle IS the error message for "required field not filled". It's the default for many forms. I'm not sure how to change that, though.

Comment: thanks for help. I found why this happening. For some reason if i set form as a spark component it doesnt work. with mx it works fine

Comment: Make sure you answer your own question and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set the required field to  ..
and set the errorMessage ="required message"

This will resolve the issue